# Issue with javascript repeating div in a form?

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I am trying to make a form that only a portion of the form is repeating.  I was advised on here to use JavaScript for that.  I keep getting an error with my current code.  Please help.

Here is the form:

```
{{ Form::open() }}
<div class="repeating">
<input type="number" name="part_number" placeholder="Part Number" />
<input type="number" name="quantity" placeholder="Quantity" />
<input type="number" name="annual_usage" placeholder="Annual Usage" />
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Add Part" />

<input type="textarea" name="comment" placeholder="Comment" />
<input type="text" name="shippingaddress" placeholder="Shipping Address" />
<input type="text" name="project_id" placeholder="Project Id" />
<input type="text" name="user_id" placeholder="User Id" />
<input type="submit" value="Send Requests" />
{{ Form::close() }}

// Add a new repeating section
$('.addPart').click(function(){
var lastRepeatingGroup = $('.repeatingSection').last();
lastRepeatingGroup.clone().insertAfter(lastRepeatingGroup);
return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you almost had it.

```
$('.addPart').click(function(){
    $('.repeating').last().clone().insertBefore(this);  // inserts before the button
    return false;
});
```

Oh, you also need to add the `.addPart` class to your button in the HTML.

(as in:)

```
<input type="submit" class="addPart" value="Add Part" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to access the element with wrong locator: there's .repeatingSection in your code, but .repeating in your html.